# ng-disabled not applying to inner span

Tags: angularjs

I have the following button:

```
<button type="submit" ng-disabled="editForm.$invalid || vm.isSaving" class="btn btn-primary" >
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-save"></span>&nbsp;
    <span data-translate="entity.action.save" ng-click="send()">Save</span>
</button>
```

My issue is the `ng-disabled` is only working on the first of the inner `<span>`, so the button becomes disabled (as does the "glyphicon-save"), but the text on the button does not, and "Save" text is still clickable. Why is this happening, whats the fix?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move your ng-click from the `<span>` to the `<button>` and you should be fine.

```
<button type="submit" ng-disabled="editForm.$invalid || vm.isSaving" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="send()">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-save"></span>&nbsp;
    <span data-translate="entity.action.save">Save</span>
</button>
```